# NameError when passing function as arg

Tags: python, function, arguments, nameerror

I have a python function test() which cycles through questions and prompts an answer and grades the results at the end. I want to pass in different, but optional modifications to the test() function like shuffle() the questions or reverse() the questions, or odds_only(), etc. When I try to pass in these functions into test() like so, I get a nameError. Can anybody please help me understand where I went wrong?

```
>>> my.test(mod=shuffle)
... NameError: name 'shuffle' is not defined


def test(self, mod=None):
    if mod is not None:
        return_value = mod()

def shuffle(self):
    list_of_questions = list(self.dictionary.keys())
    random.shuffle(list_of_questions)
    return list_of_questions
```

Comment: What is `my`? Are `test` and `shuffle` part of a class?

Comment: yes they are all part of a class, my in this case is just an object of that class

Answer (score 2):

If both test and shuffle are methods on the same class, then the call should be:

```
my.test(mod=my.shuffle)
```

Comment: If I wanted test(mod=shuffle) would I take shuffle() outside the class and put it in say main() or would it be possible to define the available mods within the test function?

Comment: You could pass in a string and then use `getattr()` to get the method of that name on `self`.